# How to build a stand-alone clang executable?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm

Is there a way to build a clang tool as a standalone executable?

Something like this [AST printer](https://github.com/philipc/clang-ast/blob/master/CMakeLists.standalone) from 5 years ago, but it no longer matches current LLVM specs, so I'm wondering how I should modify my directories and includes so everything works properly.

Comment: I put up a skeleton for out of tree clangTools [here](https://github.com/gkarlos/clang-tool-out-of-tree)

Comment: @qbit Hi, I opened up an issue on your repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CoARCT project demonstrates example tools built on Clang libtooling; all builds are done out of the LLVM tree. Perhaps it can help?

https://github.com/lanl/coarct